# JQuery - function change images automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need, that some images (for example random 5 - 8 of them) on background will automatically change for another one image (for example after 10 sec, something like that [example-link](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Be/2/) but automatically, not on hover).

```
  $('.fader').hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").fadeToggle();
  });
```

Comment: try bxSlider.. Easy to implement and cross browser Image slider plugin..

Comment: There is a reason why it says "Links to jsfiddle require code in the question" - post your code in the question, too, especially if it is not long as yours!

Comment: have you used google? there a tons of tutorials out there for exactly that.

Comment: Try http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ its a cycle plugin they have various options there too

Answer (score 6):

I made a [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/Xm2Be/394/).. Maybe it helps you.

It's pretty simple, that's the function that I execute in `setInterval`

```
var $imgs = $(".fader").find("img"),
    i = 0;

function changeImage(){
    var next = (++i % $imgs.length);
    $($imgs.get(next - 1)).fadeOut(500);
    $($imgs.get(next)).fadeIn(500);
}
var interval = setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
```

Hope it help..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` to run a function every so often, then inside it have your image changing function

```
//global variable
var bgImg = 1;

//runs every second
window.setInterval(function(){
    yourFunction();
}, 10000);

//changes background image
function   yourFunction () {
  ++bgImg;

  if(bgImg === 4){
    bgImg = 1;
  }

  if(bgImg === 1){
    $('#element').css("background-image","URL('imgs/image1.jpg')");
  }

  if(bgImg === 2){
    $('#element').css("background-image","URL('imgs/image3.jpg')");
  }

  if(bgImg === 3){
    $('#element').css("background-image","URL('imgs/image3.jpg')");
  }        
}
```

You can always add some more jquery to fade the image in out or something smoother than a plain switch

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?
Use BX slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/Xm2Be/393/

JS is as simple as this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```